# In geom_text, can "labels=scales::percent" be rounded?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a series of bar charts where the percent value is placed above each bar. I'd like to round this to 0 decimal places, but it defaults to 1 decimal place. Here's an example using mtcars.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

d <- mtcars

g <- ggplot(d, aes(gear)) +
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=factor(..x..)), stat= "count")+
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
            y= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",
        vjust = -.25)
```

This gives you:[image]

Is there a way to round these to the nearest whole number, so that the bars are labeled 47%, 38%, and 16%?

Work-arounds could include annotating the labels manually or generating a summarized data.frame from which to pull the labels. However, since I'm generating numerous tables, I'd much prefer to include all of my code within the single ggplot command.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a minimal change to your current code that will do what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

d <- mtcars

g <- ggplot(d, aes(gear)) +
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill=factor(..x..)), stat= "count")+
geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(round((..count..)/sum(..count..),2)),
            y= ((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat="count",
        vjust = -.25)
```

I have added a call to `round(...,2)` in your division that will round the ratio before passing it to `percent`.

---

Personally, I would do this outside of ggplot for clarity of code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

d <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  mutate( gear = factor(gear),
    Ratio = Count / sum(Count),
         label = percent(Ratio %>% round(2)))

g <- ggplot(d, aes(x=gear,y=Ratio,label=label,fill=gear)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(vjust=0)
g
```

When I have to go back and look at that in 6 months, it will be a lot easier to figure out what I did.

Answer (score 8):

I dealt with the same problem and solved it by adding `accuracy = 1L` in `scales::percent()` and it worked perfectly:

```
label = scales::percent(round((..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..], 
                              2), 
                        accuracy = 1L))
```

Comment: Apparently `scales::percent()` has been retired. Update to this answer is `scales::label_percent(accuracy = 1L)`

Comment: the problem is that `scales::label_percent()` doesn't take a data argument.

Comment: @nniloc `percent` seems to work, but not `label_percent`